# replacing global css with local css

Tags: css, inheritance

I am trying to edit the style of a popover. In this case I want to edit the width of the display. However, I have a global popover style sheet that applies to all popovers in the application.

```
/* ========================================================================
     Component: popovers
 ========================================================================== */

.popover {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    .arrow {
        margin-left: -7px !important;
    }
    .popover-header {
        padding: 1rem 0.75rem 0.5rem;
        display: block;
        background-color: $secondary;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .popover-body {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        color: $body-color;
    }
    .popover-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0 0.5rem;
        color: $gray-lighter;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: $body-color;
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how in my local css file I can overwrite/add to these inherited styles.

Local Style Sheet:

```
.team-activity-container {

    .icon {
      background-image: 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: inline-block
    }

    .icon .icon-team {
      background-position: -5px -5px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px
    }
}
.popover {
  background-color: aqua !important;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Edit: The local stylesheet is in the container that displays the popover, and the classes in the html are all related to the contents that fill the popover. While the popover and it's stylesheets are at the global level. how can I edit the popover at the local level without having to touch the global style sheet.

Also, The popover is from ng-bootstrap and I believe the problem is I can't overwrite the default width that bootstrap sets

Comment: If you create another css file and load it after your global file, then all the styling will overwrite the previous styles. This is assuming you only want the styles on a certain page. If you only want it on a certain popover, you can create a new class with the changes and add it to that particular popover.

Comment: Can you paste your code please!

Comment: My issue is that none of the classes I apply to the popover overwrite the global changes. As the popover's contents is edited in the local style sheets but the popover itself and all its styles are at the global level. How can I edit the popovers style itself but only at the local level.

Comment: The local style you've posted isn't valid CSS, are you using a CSS pre-processor? e.g. less or sass

Comment: Yes, these are the style themes provided to me along with whatever default styles bootstrap has set up

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the context you are in, but there are 3 main ways to overwrite existing CSS rules:

- add a new stylesheet with the new rules after the existing ones;
- if you have control over the new popover HTML, adding a class (for instance version2 so you can edit your variant in a meaningful way as .popover.version2 inheriting what is already sets and changing just what you need);
- add "!important" to the rules you add and are intended to overwrite the others, but notice that if the existing rules have already that, it's not going to work.

Depends on the context there could be other solutions like leverage on HTML tags or HTML tags properties if your new popover has some difference with the previous for examples.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: I saw you have edited your question adding stuff.
Looking at the global CSS, if your popover is in a particular container just bind the new rules to the container like this: 
.team-activity-container .popover {...rules};

Comment: For the sake of completeness (not recommended in most instances) a fourth way would be to apply an inline style on the HTML element itself.

Comment: I am using ng-bootstrap and I believe the problem is that I can't overwrite the set width of the bootstrap

Comment: @Benthon, yes but since you have control over the specific HTML (bullet point 2) better go for that way I wrote there;

Comment: @Haq.H, The only way to say definitive things, would be dealing with the code directly. Anyway, I'd say it doesn't matters if you are using Boostrap for Angular, that solution I wrote about are about CSS nature, as "cascading" style sheets. So you have to check the order of the CSSs and see what control you have over the HTML etc.

Comment: I figured out that I can edit the width in my global style sheet but I don't know how to reference the class .popover in my local file. The global is exported through its module and imported through the module of the part of the application the popover I am trying to edit is in. As shown in the above code I am trying to overwrite it but none of my local changes override the global class. The global css is at the src level and is loaded first and then the local components individual files are loaded after so there shouldn't be any issues regarding load order, am I referencing the class wrong?

Comment: I see nested selectors in your Local Stylesheet, if you're not using some pre-processor it won't work on plain CSS yet.